Do particle physics experiments need to take a possible gravitational wave background into account?
As I understand gravitational waves, we can barely detect them, because their strength is so small. On the other hand, they are presumably able to move individual particles like electrons. Does this mean particle physics experiments need to take a gravitational wave background into account? If so, how, given that we can barely detect gravitational waves in the first place and so have no idea what the background looks like?
I imagine how particle physics deals with other minute effects is to shield them, but if I'm not mistaken, gravitational waves cannot be shielded.

You state "I imagine how particle physics deals with other minute effects is to shield them", and this is not true. The effect of minute effects resides within the errors given for the various measurements in particle physics.
